# multiple forms on asp.net page for submitting feedbacks

Tags: asp.net, facebook, forms, hidden-field

I want to send data to server by enclosing it in a form. However, in asp.net I can't use more than one form with runat=server attribute. Then what is the use of using multiple forms on asp.net page. I can't access the data on the server? Like facebook enclose each post feedback data in a form and then submits this to server. How to do this in asp.net. I have to send data to server when some action occurs on a post but will have to store hiddenfield and read it with javascript is it not seems messy?

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain more about what you are trying to achieve here?

You can send data to server without having multiple forms (server-side) in one page.

If you do need it, you can use HTML forms instead of server-side forms.

Comment: Thanks. If I don't use forms then I will have to search the hiddenfields manually where I have stored my data. In short, I want to display an update like facebook and I want to know how to implement the Like and share functionality? How to do the update on the server via jquery and asp.net?

Comment: You can use a webservice with `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]` enable for your server-side function and then user getJSON() method for the remote call.